# Capturing streaming stdout & stderr in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to run a shell script in ruby that produces some outputs without exiting, a simple example would be:

```rb
o = IO.popen(%Q[ while : ; do echo hi ; sleep 0.1 ; done ]).read
p o
```

As you can see, the shell script contains a while loop, that continues until it gets killed. The `echo hi` produces endless standard output while chained with the while loop.

I want Ruby to read that streaming output produced by echo and show `"hi\n"` to the standard output as long as the shell script is running.

---

In perl for example:

```perl
open (IN, "while : ; do echo hi ; sleep 0.1 ; done |") ;
my $i = 0 ;

while (<IN>) {
    print($i++ . ' - ' . $_) ;
}
```

Output:

```
$ perl p.pl -W
0 - hi
1 - hi
2 - hi
3 - hi
4 - hi
5 - hi
6 - hi
7 - hi
8 - hi
9 - hi
10 - hi
11 - hi
12 - hi
13 - hi
...
...
...
```

---

This perl script shows the streamed output correctly, prepended with the value of variable `$i`. Is there a way to do the same in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop in Ruby:

```
io = IO.popen(%Q[ while : ; do echo hi ; sleep 0.1 ; done ])
i = 0

while io.gets
  puts "#{i} - #{$_}"
  i += 1
end
```

or a little more idiomatic:

```
IO.popen(%Q[ while : ; do echo hi ; sleep 0.1 ; done ]) do |io|
  io.each_line.with_index do |line, i|
    puts "#{i} - #{line}"
  end
end
```

You might want to set `$stdout.sync = true` when piping the script's output to another process. (Ruby buffers the output when not writing to a TTY)